# R: Count by occurrence of first character

Tags: r, string, dplyr, count, character

I have this type of data frame

```
#Data structure
```

`(list(ID = 1:5, Name = c("_PEN", "_RULER","-PAPER", "-GUM", "_BOOK"), class = "data.frame"))`

```
DF ID  Name    
   1   _PEN 
   2   _RULER
   3   -PAPER
   4   -GUM
   5   _BOOK
```

I would like to get this:

```
DF TYPE  n    
   "_"   3 
   "-"   2
```

Is there some easy to use solution with dplyr?

Comment: Try `table(gsub('[A-Za-z]', '', df$Name))`

Comment: Or in `dplyr` `count(DF %>% transmute(TYPE = substr(Name, 1, 1)), TYPE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the first character of `Name` using regular expression and use `table` to count it's occurrence.

```
stack(table(sub('(.).*', '\\1', df$Name)))
```

---

The same code in `dplyr` would be :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Name = sub('(.).*', '\\1', Name))

#  Name n
#1    _ 3
#2    - 2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Name = c("_PEN", "_RULER", "-PAPER", 
"-GUM", "_BOOK")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```